# How to use Thymeleaf layout:fragment with Spring Boot properly?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**Did I take the question wrong that I haven'T gotten any answer for 3 days?**

Thymeleaf is working basically in my project but layout:fragment doesn't want to work the way as I tried. Probably I'm doing something wrong and I read similar topics but I'd need some help with that. **I'd like the login.html has the same nav bar and footer that's defined in main.html**

main.html is in the /templates/layouts and login.html is in /templates/auth

**UPDATE**

The decorator is the main.html where I put `<div layout:fragment="content">` in the body where the content suppose to get.
What I tried is that I put `layout:decorator="layouts/main">` in the login's html tag and `layout:fragment="content"` under the body tag.

**login.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" lang="en" layout:decorator="layouts/main">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--We are choosing these two to let the browser to load faster-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/logincss.css">
  <!--this is the last one so that we can override previous boostrap styles if we want-->
<head>

<body class="signin-body">
  <div layout:fragment="content">
    <div class="container signin-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
          <div class="card signin-card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <form name="login" th:action="@{/login}" method="post" class="signin-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                  <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">Wrong username and password</div>
                  <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">You successfully logged out</div>
                  <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="true">
                  <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="true">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block signin-btn" type="submit">Login</button>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
                  <!-- <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Remember me <a href="#"> Need help?</a></label> -->
                  <a class="new-account" href="/registration">Create New Account</a>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**main.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
  <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2dafcd6f62.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS // Let's connect the CSS to the grid system -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" th:href="@{css/style.css}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" th:href="@{css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <!-- ########## MENU BAR ########## -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active"></li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" th:text="${references}" target="_blank">some text...</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" th:text="${qualifications}">
              qualification or something
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" th:text="${it}">Some text...</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" th:text="${vaadin}">Some text...</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" th:text="${java}">Some text...</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" th:text="${myproject}">
              some text...
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="pdf/modulzaro.pdf" th:text="${exam}">some text...</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <input class="button-logout" type="submit" value="Log Out" />
      </form>
    </nav>
    <div layout:fragment="content">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--FOOTER-->
  <footer class="footer bg-dark">
    <!--we can put here our own container-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 socialWrapper">
          <p class="contact">Email:
            <br>Phone: </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-9 footer-font-icons">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <!--target="_blank" will open our github page on a new page-->
            <i class="fa fa-github-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**WebConf.java**

```
@Configuration
public class WebConf implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("auth/login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the source of the issue:

I forgot to add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Now it works.